# How to debug ARM register dump after a reset?

Tags: arm, stack-overflow, rtos

I'm using Tiva TM4C129XNCZAD based on 32-bit ARM® Cortex®-M4F in a TI_RTOS environment. I'm getting an unexpected reset during the normal flow of the system. After reset, I get the following register values. How can I understand what caused the reset using the below register values?

```
0xffffffff
R1 = 0x00000000  R9  = 0xffffffff
R2 = 0x2000a26c  R10 = 0xffffffff
R3 = 0x2000a26c  R11 = 0xffffffff
R4 = 0x2003ee54  R12 = 0x00000000
R5 = 0x20000a80  SP(R13) = 0x20034e18
R6 = 0x2003d664  LR(R14) = 0x00073135
R7 = 0x2003bbc4  PC(R15) = 0x00000000
PSR = 0x60000000
ICSR = 0x0440f803
MMFSR = 0x00
BFSR = 0x00
UFSR = 0x0002
HFSR = 0x40000000
DFSR = 0x00000001
MMAR = 0xe000ed34
BFAR = 0xe000ed38
AFSR = 0x00000000
Terminating execution...
```

Comment: what did you see when you looked each of these up in the documentation?  please show the debug so far.  waht code is at that lr address?

Comment: `PC(R15) = 0x00000000` jumping by un-initialised function pointer ?

Answer (score 0):

The ARM core register values *after* reset are unlikely to be relevant.

The TM4C129XNCZAD  specifically has a `RESC` (Reset Cause) register in the System Control register block.  That will tell you whether the last reset was a POR, Watchdog, brown-out, oscillator fail etc.  The register is at address: `0x400FE05C`; refer to the [data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/spms444b/spms444b.pdf?ts=1634209786205&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) p.280 for details.

Determining the direct cause of the reset will inform you of where you need to look for the indirect cause (software error, hardware fault, inadequate power-supply etc.)  For example if you have a Bus Fault exception, and the exception handler is an infinite loop, you may get a watchdog reset - or the handler may simply issue a software (NVIC) reset.  Placing a breakpoint in the exception handler(s) is a good place to start.  If you are getting an fault exception you can inspect the state in the exception handler rather than *after* reset.

Confusingly the data sheet refers to the exception handler registers with unconventional names: `FAULTSTAT`, `HFAULTSTAT`, `MMADDR`, `FAULTADDR`.  These are in fact the `CFSR`, `HFSR`, `MMAR` and `BFAR` respectively in your register dump (actually the dump has no CFSR but that is simply a combination of `MFSR`, `UFSR` and `DFSR`).  Details of the exception registers can be found [here](https://www.keil.com/appnotes/files/apnt209.pdf).

Your register dump shows that the the processor is in debug HALT at PC address 0x0000000. `UFSR = 0x0002` indicates an attempt to switch to ARM mode from Thumb mode (Cortex-M does not support ARM mode).  This occurs when a jump/branch occurs without the address LSB=1 (Thumb bit).  However I don't think the UFSR is valid after a reset - you need to inspect it from within the fault handler itself.  Moreover address 0x0000000 is the location of the vector table and specifically, on reset:

- Address at 0x00000000 is loaded to SP
- Address at 0x00000004 is loaded to PC

As such it is hard to see how `PC=0x00000000` can be a valid state.  It suggests that you have no valid start address.
If this register dump is in fact from the fault handler and not *after* reset as you suggest, then perhaps you have a jump/branch to an invalid *even* address which would cause the `UFSR = 0x0002` - in Thumb all jump targets are *odd* (the LSB is ignored as the actual address is always even).

Once you have determined the `RESC` value you might then post a further question on how to diagnose or locate the error if it is not clear.  The simplest and fastest method to determining a software cause of a reset/exception is to use the Embedded Trace Macrocell (ETM) with suitable debugger hardware/software to record the code execution immediately prior to the event.  However your board may not expose the trace pins or you may not possess suitable debug tools.